# Copy files in parallel from remote servers using some command on terminal?

Tags: linux, scp, gnu-parallel

I am copying files from remote server to my local server using below scp command. I just type below command on the terminal and it starts copying.

```
scp -r user@machineA:/data/process/* /data/process/
```

Now since on remote servers we have around 100 files and each file size is around 11 GB so above command will copy one file at a time. Is there any way by which I can copy 5 files at a time in parallel with some command that I can run directly on the terminal?

I also have GNU parallel installed but not sure how can I use it here which can help me copy files in parallel by running directly on terminal? Or if there is any other way then I am open for that as well.

Comment: You're quite possibly disk or network bound, in which case running multiple copies in parallel will gain you nothing. Have you done the maths to see if it's worth it?

Comment: Yes it will help me for sure. And there is no harm in trying out since we do this very rare and whenever we do this it takes time so I want to experiment and see whether this parallel copy helps or not. If it doesn't help then we won't use it but if it helps then it's a plus thing for us.

Comment: Are they text files or binary data?

Comment: They all are binary data, mostly memory mapped files.

Comment: Would you want to parallelise one file each from five servers, or five files from one server?

Comment: My above command is copying from one remote server (machineA) and we have around 100 files to copy so five files in parallel from that remote server and keep doing until all the files get copied successfully to local server.

Comment: It is true that there is no harm in trying, but it would be interesting to find out where the bottleneck actually is. How much bandwidth is left unused during the transfer? What speed are you achieving in MB/s? Do you have an SSD on the receiving box? What's the sustained write speed?

Comment: Yes we do have SSD on the local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the command to be run on the remote server, involving `find` and `parallel`:

```
find /data/process/ -type f | parallel scp {} user@machineB:/data/process/
```

**Edit:**

See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) on how to control the number of jobs to be executed in parallel.

> The number of concurrent jobs is given with `--jobs` or the equivalent `-j`.
>   By default `--jobs` is the same as the number of CPU cores.
>   `--jobs 0` will run as many jobs in parallel as possible.

**Edit:**

This should be another question, and has already been asked and answered: how to run a command on a remote machine?

```
ssh user@machineA 'find /data/process/ -type f | parallel scp {} user@machineB:/data/process/'
```

Comment: I need to run this command on local server where I am copying right? And how many files will it copy? I dont see a number to control that? And what is `9001` here?

Comment: This command is to be run on the remote server containing the files to be copied. It will copy all files found by `find`, there's no limit on the total number. Ignore the `9001` as it is a leftover from a copy/paste.

Comment: If I have around 100 files then it will start 100 files copying in parallel? It will be great if I can control the number of parallel copy. There is no way to run the command on the local server instead?

Comment: `--jobs` controls the number of `scp` processes running in parallel. It defaults to the number of CPU cores.