# Copy Files between Wondows and Linux parallelly

Tags: putty, gnu-parallel, file-transfer

I have a problem to transfer files from windows dir to Linux parallelly via internet.
For example, using putty, I have 8 files in my windows directory, and should send them to the Linux server parallelly, transferring single file is no problem, but I don't know to transfer multifiles parallelly.

Comment: Putty is not designed for advanced (multiple) file transfer. Use any other file transfer protocol, not a terminal client over ssh!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallelise rsync using GNU Parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189878/parallelise-rsync-using-gnu-parallel).  *If all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail:* you need to use another tool to send these files or open multiple putty sessions to send files in parallel.  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

Here's the command to be run on the remote server, involving find and parallel:

```
 find /data/process/ -type f | parallel scp {} user@machineB:/data/process/
```

See the documentation on how to control the number of jobs to be executed in parallel.

```
The number of concurrent jobs is given with --jobs or the equivalent -j.
By default --jobs is the same as the number of CPU cores.
--jobs 0 will run as many jobs in parallel as possible.
```

Found it here: [Copy files in parallel from remote servers using some command on terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410959/copy-files-in-parallel-from-remote-servers-using-some-command-on-terminal)